# Accessing CustomProperties on Worksheet with Name

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, office-interop

I'm trying to access a custom property on a worksheet by using the name of the property, but it seems this is not supported (at least not in C#, I saw others reporting that it works in VB and documentation also says so). Can someone confirm that this is not working in C#? Here is example code:

```
activeWorkSheet.CustomProperties.Add("Test", 123);
// Accessing by index works, but by name it doesn't. 
// The documentation says access by name should be possible
var works = activeWorkSheet.CustomProperties.Item[1].Value;
var doenstWork = activeWorkSheet.CustomProperties.Item["Test"].Value;
```

I know that a workaround is just some method that iterates over all the properties and finds the right one, but I would really like to avoid any additional overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone confirm that this is not working in C#?

Just tried with Office 2013 preview and version 15 of the Interop API, and I can confirm that this does not work in C# (throws a `COMException` with the message of "Type mismatch").

I have checked the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.customproperties.item%28v=office.14%29.aspx), which states that it should be perfectly legal to use the key name as index for the `Item` indexer - from the docs for the `CustomProperties.Item` property, it states that the following indexer is available:

```
CustomProperty this[
    Object Index
] { get; }
```

... and in the following text, the docs states:

> **Parameters**
>
> *Index*
>
> Type: `System.Object`
>
> Required Object. The **name** or index number of the object.

... so since the documentation states that the name is a valid key, the behavior we experience might likely be a bug.

Comment: Yes, very strange indeed. Well thanks for testing it out, I thought maybe I was using it wrongly.